# HTML onClick to get user location with geolocation

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

```
<body>
     <script src="script.js"></script>
     <div id="map">Get your Location</div>
     <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=(API_KEY)&callback=getLocation"></script>
</body>
```

I just want to create a button where upon clicking the "Get your Location" will go to the getLocation() function inside the my script.js. Right now, my code will just show where I am when loading the page, not after the button is clicked. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function **getLocation** will be called once map gets loaded in your HTML, as you have passed that method as **callback** in the url for google maps.
If you want to call function on click of some element then you should add **onclick** attribute to that element. In your case you want to call **getLocation** on click of div then you should do below :
`<div id"map" onclick="getLocation()">Get Your Location</div>`

Answer (score 1):

Based on [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp) you can use below code:

```js
function getLocation() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos) {
    //You have your locaton here
      console.log("Latitude: " + pos.coords.latitude +
        "Longitude: " + pos.coords.longitude);
    });
  } else {
    console.log("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="getLocation()">Get Location</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, all you need to do is add this to your div:

```
<div id="map" onclick="getLocation()">Get your Location</div>
```